# anchor tags in my URL not working

Tags: url

I'm having issues with using anchors in my URLs. For example, I have a url http://myurlhere.com/page#anchor, the site fails to go to the anchor. Has anyone experienced this issue?

Edit: When I'm testing on local, the local URLs + anchor tags work, but when I test on my production servers, UTM tags are being added to the URLs, and the anchors seem to be ignored and not appended. I tried manually editing the URLs to include the UTM tags, but duplicate UTM tags are then appended to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the anchor does actually exist on the page (always double check) and the URL is correct when the page loads, the only two things it could be are a browser problem or JavaScript is resetting your scroll position. After checking on a couple of different browsers start going through your JavaScript plugins and the code you have written yourself to see what the culpret is.

Comment: Hey Johnathan, thanks for your response. Can you take a look at my edit?

Answer (score 0):

Anchor-links will not work when followed by UTM-tags or other parameters. Most probably you will break your UTM-tags when appending it to an anchor.

You will have no other possibility than to add the anchor-link at the end of the UTM-parameters.